# JqueryUI slider is not working when parsing dom element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using simple HTML dom parser.
Everything works well with my code but jqueryui is not working and for some sites it doesn't display images.
Please check live site [here](http://www.larevuedekenza.fr/)
And please try with simple HTML [dom parser](https://tool-super-star.c9users.io/).

Please enter URL in the text field with URL.
You can see that images are not loaded and sliders are not working.
Here's my code

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$data = new simple_html_dom();

if ( isset($_REQUEST['url_name']) ) {
    if ( strpos($_REQUEST['url_name'], "http://") === false && strpos($_REQUEST['url_name'], "//") === false ) {
        $_REQUEST['url_name']="http://".$_REQUEST['url_name'];
    }

    $url_name = $_REQUEST['url_name'];
    if ( strpos($_REQUEST['url_name'], "/") === false ) {
        $url_name = $_REQUEST['url_name'].'/';
    }

    // Load HTML from an URL 
    $data->load_file($_REQUEST['url_name']);
    foreach ( $data->find('img') as $element ) {
        $element->target='_blank';
        if (    strpos($element, ".com") === false
             && strpos($element, ".net") === false
             && strpos($element, ".org") === false
             && strpos($element, "http://") === false
             && strpos($element, "https://") === false
           ){
            $element->src=$url_name.$element->src;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $data->find('style') as $element ) {
        if (    strpos($element, ".com") === false
             && strpos($element, ".net") === false
             && strpos($element, ".org") === false
             && strpos($element, "http://") === false
             && strpos($element, "https://") === false
           ){
            $element->src=$url_name.$element->src;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $data->find('script') as $element ) {
        if (    strpos($element, ".com") === false
             && strpos($element, ".net") === false
             && strpos($element, ".org") === false
             && strpos($element, "http://") === false
             && strpos($element, "https://") === false
           ){
            $element->src=$url_name.$element->src;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $data->find('link') as $element ) {
        if (     strpos($element, ".com") === false
             && strpos($element, ".net") === false
             && strpos($element, ".org") === false
             && strpos($element, "http://") === false
             && strpos($element, "https://") === false
           ){
            $element->href=$url_name.$element->href;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $data->find('a') as $element ) {
        if (    strpos($element->href, ".com") === false
             && strpos($element->href, ".net") === false
             && strpos($element->href, ".org") === false
             && strpos($element->href, "http://") === false
             && strpos($element->href, "https://") === false
           ){
            $element->href = "form_submit.php?url_name=".$url_name.$element->href;
        } else {
            $element->href = "form_submit.php?url_name=".$element->href;
        }
    }

    echo $newHtml;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Gjohn sorry the test url is https://tool-super-star.c9users.io/

Comment: @Gjohn all images sizes are set to 0px for http://www.larevuedekenza.fr/ with test url.

Comment: @virendra do you know how to solve? plz help me.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this code? It's incredibly hard to read. Little tip: if you find yourself describing parts of your code with singleline comments, you should remove the comment, and move that block into a separate function.

Comment: `strpos($element, ".com")` .....a DOMNode is not a string. Only for `<a>` you test the attribute( `href`)

Comment: However, instead of modifying all these attributes you may simply add  a `<base href>`

Answer (score 0):

## What are you trying to do?

#### I'll just guess that you want a list of all hosted img, css, js, and urls.

1. `$newHtml` was never defined anywhere in your code.
2. What is your `simple_html_dom` class? I'll assume it's this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

   - either that, or you intended to `echo $data;` at the end.
3. functions! at the very least!

## You'll have to figure out the rest

Since I don't really know what you're going for, what your `simple_html_dom` actually is, all I can do is introduce you to some more advanced 
coding concepts.

- Proper use of whitespace for code-styling

  - some people will disagree with my choices here, but it make for a vast improvement in readability.
- If you have really long lines, break them up.
- If you have blocks of nearly identical code repeating throughout your code, it should probably be a function.
- When debugging/troubleshooting, either echo everything or use a debugger (xdebug).
- Comment your code better, that I haven't here should teach you why you always should.

Adjusted code:

```php
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$data = new simple_html_dom();

if ( isset($_REQUEST['url_name']) ) {
    if ( strpos($_REQUEST['url_name'], "http://") === false && strpos($_REQUEST['url_name'], "//") === false ) {
        $_REQUEST['url_name']="http://".$_REQUEST['url_name'];
    }

    $data->my_url_name = $_REQUEST['url_name'];
    if ( strpos($_REQUEST['url_name'], "/") === false ) {
        $data->my_url_name = $_REQUEST['url_name'].'/';
    }

    echo "<div style='border:1px solid blue;'>";

        // Load HTML from an URL
        $data->load_file($_REQUEST['url_name']);

        modifyUrls($data, 'img', array('target' => '_blank'));
        modifyUrls($data, 'style');
        modifyUrls($data, 'script');
        modifyUrls($data, 'link', array(), 'href');

        foreach ( $data->find('a') as $element ) {
            if ( checkurl($element->href) ) {
                echo $element->href = "form_submit.php?url_name=". $data->my_url_name . $element->href;
            } else {
                echo $element->href = "form_submit.php?url_name=". $element->href;
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }

        echo "</div><div style='border:1px solid red;'>";
        echo $data;
        echo "</div>";
    }

function modifyUrls(&$dataObj, $target, $options = array(), $urlAttribute = "src") {
    foreach ( $dataObj->find($target) as $element ) {
        if ( !empty($options) ) {
            foreach ($options as $field => $value) {
                $element->{$field} = $value;
            }
        }

        if ( checkurl($element) ) {
            echo $element->{$urlAttribute} = $dataObj->my_url_name . $element->{$urlAttribute};
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}

function checkurl($url){
    if (    strpos($url, ".com") === false
        && strpos($url, ".net") === false
        && strpos($url, ".org") === false
        && strpos($url, "http://") === false
        && strpos($url, "https://") === false
    ){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```